# How do I check href attribute and if needed add full url address?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to check the href attribute and if it does not contain the full path, I want to replace it with full URL? Should I use JavaScript which does that but don't work on IE 8?

My JS:

```
fullUrl = $(this).filter('[href^='+document.location.protocol+']').attr('href') 
    ? true : false;

url = fullUrl ? 
    $(this).filter('[href^='+document.location.protocol+']').attr('href') 
    : document.location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + $(this).attr('href');
```

I need to check if href contain full url or not:

**href: "/path/other.html" (part)**

**href:"http://domain.com/path/other.html" (full url)**

And then if i have part url href, i must add domain and recreate href to full url!

Comment: Your code doesn't replace the `href` attribute...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full url is available via the `.href` property.

Typically there's no need to set it to the attribute, but if you want to, you could do this:

```
$('a[href]').attr('href', function() { return this.href; });
```

This finds all `<a>` elements that have an `href` attribute, and updates its `href` using the [`attr()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method by passing a function as the second parameter, which returns the value of the `.href` property.

---

If you just wanted a list of them, you can use the [`map()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method.

```
var hrefs = $('a[href]').map(function() { return this.href; }).get();
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/EDhhD/

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to explicitly check that the path isn't already the full path, just add an `if` statement to my first example.

```
$('a[href]').attr('href', function(i,hrf) { 
    if( hrf.indexOf( 'http' ) !== 0 ) return this.href; 
});
```

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't correct! sorry :(. Let me explain again:

Comment: @Faraona: Looking at your updates, it would seem that my first solution would work, except that it doesn't check the current `href`. I'll give an update in case you really need that check.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this:

```
$(this).attr('href', function(i, v) {
    if ( v.indexOf('http:') === -1 ) {
        v = document.location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + '/' + v; 
    }
    return v;
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/bwmQ5/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get a meaningful result of calling `attr` on multiple items. You should do your check/replacement in a loop, one item at a time:

```
$(this).filter('[href^='+document.location.protocol+']').each(function(){
    var fullUrl = $(this).attr('href') ? true : false;
    var url = fullUrl ? $(this).attr('href') : document.location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + $(this).attr('href');
    alert(url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will ensure all anchors on your page have the protocol in the href:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{  
    var str_len = document.location.protocol.length;
    $('a').each(function()
    {
        if($(this).attr('href').substring(0,str_len) != document.location.protocol)
        {
            $(this).attr('href',document.location.protocol + '//' + $(this).attr('href'));
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3XQXL/